# Which site of stack exchange is the best place to discuss domain deals?

Tags: support, domain-name

like:

whether domain xx is good or not

whether a domain is worth $1000 or not

how to buy a domain from a foreign vendor

Answer (score 3):

> whether domain xx is good or not
>
> whether a domain is worth $1000 or not

These are a matter of opinion.   These would be off-topic on any Stack Exchange website.   Questions must be answerable based on facts, experience, and evidence.  Questions asking "is X good" or "is X worth Y" depend a lot on who you are.   Some people may feel one way and other people another.

> how to buy a domain from a foreign vendor

You could ask about the mechanics of buying a domain on Webmasters Stack Exchange

Comment: any other appropriate forum?

Comment: @questionhang You could perhaps try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=webmasters.stackexchange.com), although you may not get much of a response?